# How does object-oriented programming in JS fit for DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to implement the OOP to manipulate the DOM but there are certain things that I don't know where to place for example addEventListeners, a punctual case that I'm facing is, I have created an object that works with some elements of the DOM and I need to identify the scroll level that the user makes in that object (Menu). One way to do this without the implementation of the OOP is to do it:

```
//===============================================
//File Menu.JS
//===============================================

exports.Menu = () => {
  //Implementación sin OOP
  const mainNav     = document.getElementById( 'main-nav' );
  const features    = document.getElementById( 'features-container' );
  let lastScrollTop = 0;

  const fixMenu = () => {

    const currentScroll = window.scrollY;

    //give new styles to navbar
    if ( currentScroll > 0 ) {
      mainNav.classList.add( 'is-scrolled' );
    } else {
      mainNav.classList.remove( 'is-scrolled' );
    }

    //show or hide navbar according to scroll direction
    if ( currentScroll > lastScrollTop ) {
      mainNav.classList.add( 'is-up' );
    } else {
      mainNav.classList.remove( 'is-up' );
    }

    lastScrollTop = currentScroll;
  };

  window.addEventListener( 'scroll', fixMenu );
}

//===============================================
//File Index.JS
//===============================================

import {Menu} from './menu';

const menu    = document.getElementById('menu');
const toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');

Menu(menu, toggler);
```

Now how do I implement the above in OOP, where I place the addEventListeners? within the same object? or on the outside?

```
 //===============================================
 //File(Object) Menu.js
 //===============================================    

exports.Menu = function ( menu, toggler ) {

  const self = this;

  function _isDom ( el ) {
    return (el !== null && (el.nodeType === 1 || el.nodeType === 11))
      ? el
      : self.error = '[API] target is null or undefined';
  }

  self.initialize = () => {
    self.menu       = _isDom( menu );
    self.toggler    = _isDom( toggler );
    self.initScroll = 0;
    self.travelled  = 0;
  };

  self.initialize();
};

//===============================================
//File Index.JS
//===============================================    

import {Menu} from './menu';

const menu    = document.getElementById('menu');
const toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');

const mainMenu = new Menu(menu, toggler);
```

Comment: Side note: `window.addEventListener( 'scroll', fixMenu );`  --- you should add a debounce or throttle to that. https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: Its truth @CodyG. its just an illustrate example, but i am a little confiuse about how to implement DOM manipulation to OOP where put the addeventlistener in a especific object or inside an existin object, how to trigger events and more.